# .htaccess help needed to make nice looking referral link

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need help regarding nice looking referral link. for example here is a referral link

```
http://www.my-domain.com/register.php?ref=john.doe
```

this is a perfect url but not looks good like the following

```
http://www.my-domain.com/john.doe
```

how can i achieve this using .htaccess file? please note that, i have index.php, member.php and other many php files in my server. moreover, if someone write my-domain.com it need to hit index.php file.

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example you can use the following `.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+\.php)$ $1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)$ register.php?ref=$1
```

This works as following:

- Line 1: Sets your index file to `index.php` if someone accesses `http://www.my-domain.com/`. This should already be working, but just in case.
- Line 2: Enables the `RewriteEngine`.
- Line 3: If someone wants to access anything (technically: anything with at least one character) ending with `.php`, it is just forwarded (i.e. `foo.php` will be mapped to `foo.php`). `[NC,L]` enables case insensitive matching (for the extension - you never know) and prevents any further rules from being executed. Otherwise the second one would also match every time.
- Line 4: If someone wants to access anything matching "at least one character, a dot, at least one more character", then this will be mapped to `register.php?ref=<input>`

Note: This will effectively prevent all user names ending with `.php`, but allow access to all your files. It will also prevent user names containing less or more than one dot and it will in its current form not work if your files or user names contain any other characters (e.g. `foo_bar.php` or `i_love_php`). But those two limitations can be easily overcome if needed, just provide more details regarding expected behaviour.

You *could* add a `RewriteCond` to check if there actually exists a `.php` file with the requested name and treat it as user name otherwise, but I really don't think you *should* do that (think about adding new files).

Comment: absolutely perfect. this is what i was really looking for. thanks Marvin.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+\.php)$ $1 [NC,L]` is a waste of an internal redirect. It's not necessary. You should use conditions to tell it to ignore real files or real directories .

Comment: i need another help. i have a directory named admin which means that www.mydomain.com/admin/ is not accessible for this rewrite rules. how to tell rewrite rules to skip admin folder? and similarly css, js and images folder

Comment: @user1911703 did you try my answer at all? That is the reason I did it that way and is the proper way to account for **real** directories and files.

Comment: @PanamaJack i have tried your one but http://www.my-domain.com/john.doe shows me page not found.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you need. This rule will handle nice link and also redirect old link to nice link.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+register\.php\?ref=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /register.php?ref=$1 [L]
```